# taking the average of POSIX times in Y-m-d H:M:S format

Tags: r, time, posix

I have a list of times in POSIXct format ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "EST")
that I would like to take the average of:

```
> data
                  time
1  2015-10-08 17:20:17
2  2015-10-08 17:16:29
3  2015-10-08 17:28:34
4  2015-10-08 17:20:54
5  2015-10-08 17:47:37
6  2015-10-08 16:44:18
7  2015-10-08 17:36:42
8  2015-10-08 17:44:00
9  2015-10-08 17:54:36
10 2015-10-08 17:45:09
11 2015-10-08 17:50:31
12 2015-10-08 17:31:18
13 2015-10-08 17:11:28
14 2015-10-08 16:37:40
15 2015-10-08 17:57:28
16 2015-10-08 16:54:24
17 2015-10-08 17:11:46
18 2015-10-08 16:55:32
19 2015-10-08 17:31:29
20 2015-10-08 17:44:44
21 2015-10-08 16:51:12
22 2015-10-08 16:41:36
23 2015-10-08 17:20:50
24 2015-10-08 17:30:37
25 2015-10-08 12:32:14
26 2015-10-08 17:30:27
27 2015-10-08 17:21:11
28 2015-10-08 17:23:58
29 2015-10-08 17:10:19
30 2015-10-08 16:58:50
31 2015-10-08 17:01:13
32 2015-10-08 16:58:25
33 2015-10-08 17:33:15
34 2015-10-08 16:35:51
35 2015-10-08 17:48:00
36 2015-10-08 17:03:43
37 2015-10-08 17:09:46
38 2015-10-08 17:14:50
39 2015-10-08 17:26:35
40 2015-10-08 17:27:33
41 2015-10-08 17:45:03
42 2015-10-08 17:20:20
43 2015-10-08 17:32:20
44 2015-10-08 16:32:56
45 2015-10-08 17:05:29
46 2015-10-08 17:01:46
```

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1444342817.5, 1444342589, 1444343314, 
1444342854, 1444344457.5, 1444340658, 1444343802, 1444344240, 
1444344876, 1444344309, 1444344631.5, 1444343478.5, 1444342288.5, 
1444340260, 1444345048.5, 1444341264.5, 1444342306, 1444341332, 
1444343489, 1444344284, 1444341072, 1444340496.5, 1444342850.5, 
1444343437, 1444325534, 1444343427, 1444342871, 1444343038, 1444342219, 
1444341530, 1444341673, 1444341505, 1444343595, 1444340151, 1444344480.5, 
1444341823.5, 1444342186, 1444342490.5, 1444343195.5, 1444343253.5, 
1444344303, 1444342820.5, 1444343540, 1444339976.5, 1444341929.5, 
1444341706.5), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = "time", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried to take the average with the following code but this did not work:

`tapply(data$time,mean)`

Comment: `tapply` needs a grouping variable.  What is your expected output?  If it is for the entire column, I get `mean(data[,1])#[1] "2015-10-09 03:42:14 IST"`

Comment: It is not clear how the average should be calculated. The simplest thing would be to take the midpoint between the earliest and the latest observation. Should the number of observations enter into the weighting of the average calculation? As an example: should the time span between 17:20 and 17:40 be considered as more or less important than an other interval of 20 minutes that contains less or more observations, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this gives the result that you are looking for. It provides the average time at which the observations in the list were recorded:

```
as.POSIXct(mean(as.numeric(data$time)), origin='1970-01-01',tz="EST")
#[1] "2015-10-08 17:12:14 EST"
```

The idea is to take the average of the timestamps, by using `as.numeric()` to convert the `POSIX` values (back) into timestamps. The numerical average of these timestamps can be computed by simply using `mean()`. After that, the average timestamp is converted back into a time/date format with `as.POSIXct()`. The result depends on the choice of the timezone.

---

If you don't have to worry about time zones, you may simply use

```
mean.POSIXct(data$time)
```

or even just `mean(data$time)`.